# Labels Not Recognized

Tags: powershell, label

I am somewhat new to Power Shell.  I am working on scripting to automate a PC build process.  The overall design of the process is that the resulting program, when initially runs, asks the user for some data, stores that data in the registry for later retrieval, then goes about it's tasks.  It renames the machine, joins it to a domain, and does some other basic setup.  Because of the reboots needed for renaming and joining the domain, I am using a status value in the registry that is read when the program runs.  I am using switch to jump to the appropriate label in the script, based on the stage.  I am also using labels where I validate user input.  This is where I am running into issues - the labels are throwing errors.

I have looked at a number of sites about labels, and based on what I see, I have them correct - unless I misunderstood something (which is always a possibility).  I have done the following:

```
:Label
<code goes here>

:Label
    {
    <code goes here>
    }

:Label <code goes here>
```

All of which behave the same.

This is an example of code that uses labels and is throwing errors (later parts are not even executing at this point).  This is part of the user input section.

```
# User Input
:UserInput Write-Output "Please provide the following information in order to properly image the system:"

    :Country $Country=Read-Host "Enter 2 character destination country code"
        IF(!$Country)
            {
            Write-Output "The destination country is required!"
            Break :Country
            }
```

That piece of code generates the following errors:

```
:UserInput : The term ':UserInput' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At <sanitized for my protection>Kiosk_PC_Build_V0_1a.ps1:79 char:1
+ :UserInput Write-Output "Please provide the following information in  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:UserInput:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


:Country : The term ':Country' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At <sanitized for my protection>Kiosk_PC_Build_V0_1a.ps1:81 char:5
+     :Country $Country=Read-Host "Enter 2 character destination countr ...
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:Country:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I get the same error 'The term....' for each of the permutations I am using.  I have the feeling I am missing something simple.

Comment: A label **must be followed by the looping keyword**.

Comment: See [about_Break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-6). It has examples for labeled loops.

Comment: To clarify (in other words, making sure I understand this correctly), a label can ONLY be used to start a loop?  Is there another way to do the branching based on value that I need?  I suppose I could do something like :label while(!$foo) { <some code> $foo = 1 } (Formatted a lot better, of course).